# Android keyboard issue when switching layouts with "?123" button

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-inputtype

In Android if we press `?123` key (or similar) on software keyboard it shows us digits/symbols layout. And it will automatically turns back to alphabetical layout when `whitespace` pressed or `EditText` cleared by app from code.

Is there any option to turn off this "auto reset" behavior? Maybe some flag for `EditText`, `InputConnection`, `InputType`, etc.

Note that numeric keyboard is not suitable. It must be common keyboard (`InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT`) which just allows only manual switching between layouts.

Comment: Try to reseach this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html#setInputMethod%28android.os.IBinder,%20java.lang.String%29

I am not sure, I think you need to save inputMethod and restore it from app. I am not really sure.

Comment: at first glance it seems that it has something to do with my question. however i don't understand how i can apply this. it's not like I'm dealing with the various InputMethods.